# Eclipse Maven project locking target/checkout directory after running release:perform

Tags: git, eclipse, maven

This seems to be a new problem after recent update to Eclipse. I have an Eclipse Maven project using Git.

Running a Maven release from the command line:

```
mvn release:perform
```

somehow causes Eclipse to lock the `target\checkout` folder, such that it is not possible to run `mvn clean` unless I close Eclipse.  The error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project broker-permserver: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\coding\dev\broker-permserver\target\checkout\.git\objects\pack\pack-7d131c816204f9e3e9105e10e092fa77b3bac607.pack -> [Help 1]
```

If I try to delete the directory from within Eclipse, I see the error:

```
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Folder contains an active Git repository.
The folder cannot be moved, renamed or deleted until the team provider is disconnected.
```

**Eclipse Version info**:
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

**Egit Version:**
6.5.0.202303070854-r

Comment: Generally, you should avoid to run such commands in the IDE. It is better to do release builds on your build server, like Jenkins, GitLab CI, etc.

Comment: Why is there a git repository *inside* your Maven project?

Comment: During the release prozess the maven release plugin will checkout the state of the defined tag into target/checkout to run the real `mvn deploy`... that's the reason why there is a git repo inside a maven project but that should be no problem because `target` should be part of `.gitignore` but within Eclipse and particular on Windows the directories/files will tried to access which locks those file exclusively which produces the issue... and do not run such things from Eclipse better on CI/CD server as @JFabianMeier already suggested...

Comment: @khmarbaise: We are in the process of moving our builds to CI/CD server (which is time consuming for a small team with hundreds of applications).   But I have literally been doing this process for *years* without any issue.  This is a *new* Eclipse problem.  I was hoping maybe someone else had experienced this and found a solution.

Comment: @ntind: because that's where I am running mvn release:perform and it is cloning the repository into the target folder.  I've been doing this for a long time with no problems.  Suddenly the behavior changed.

Comment: Creating a release form within your IDE is simply an anti pattern for a decade or even more ... Best would be to move to your CI/CD server and an intermediate step is simply to use the plain command line... that will solve the problem... I don't see problem with `mvn -B  release:prepare release:perform`....doing that from your command line...

Comment: @khmarbaise: in my question I wrote "Running a Maven release from the command line:"  It just happens that I have Eclipse open at the same time as I am running it from the command line.

Comment: @JFabianMeier: to clarify, I never was running these commands inside the IDE.  It's just that the IDE happens to be open when I run it.  The main issue is that this never used to be a problem.

Comment: If you have Eclipse open at the same time it accesses the files and locks those files... that's it...